# Refreshing winform ComboBox datasource on closing a dialog form

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a settings form, on which there is a combo box that I fill with divisions from the database. Next to this combo box there is a "new" button the user can click to create a new division.

When the New button is clicked, a dialog form pops up for user input and saving the new division. I would like for the combo box on the settings form to refresh when the dialog form is closed, but I can't seem to get it.

I created a function to fill the combo box:

```
        private void fillDivisionsCmboBox()
    {
        Divisions divs = new Divisions();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        //FILL DIVISIONS DROP DOWN
        dt = divs.GetActiveDivisions();

        if (divs.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + divs.Error,
                "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
        else if (dt.Rows.Count <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: No Divisions returned. Please create divisions with the \"New\" button.",
                "Divisions: Empty Reuturn",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
        else
        {
            this.cmbo_divisions.DataSource = dt;
            this.cmbo_divisions.DisplayMember = "title";
            this.cmbo_divisions.ValueMember = "ID";
            this.cmbo_divisions.SelectedIndex = -1;
            this.cmbo_divisions.Text = "Select a Division";

            //HANDLE UI VISIBILITY
            this.grp_divSettings.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

which I call on the Activated event of the settings form:

```
    private void frm_settings_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fillDivisionsCmboBox();
    }
```

Here I call the dialog form, from the new button:

```
        private void btn_new_division_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form newdiv = new frm_new_division();
        newdiv.ShowDialog();
    }
```

I did this in the hopes that it would refresh the combo box when the dialog is closed, but the activated event isn't triggered when the dialog box is closed... How can I achieve a refresh of the combo box on closing the dialog box?

Thank you for your time

Comment: I can add it right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execution of code in the first Form pauses when you show the second Form as a modal dialog.

So just call `fillDivisionsCmboBox()` immediately after displaying the second Form, instead of in the Form.Activated event, and it'll run when the user closes the Form.

```
private void btn_new_division_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var newdiv = new frm_new_division())
        newdiv.ShowDialog();

    fillDivisionsCmboBox();
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this refresh before a new division is even created, resulting in the new division not showing up in the combo box?

Comment: Ah, ok I just saw your edit... very interesting, thank you! I'll try that right away.

Comment: works beautifully - thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as the option becomes available.